# CS-cart product list short description not always there...

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

The product short description in the grid_list template was not showing at all in the featured products or similar products sections. It shows fine, however, in the category pages.

I tried adding `{debug}` to see if that revealed anything, and all the short descriptions suddenly showed up as expected. So I removed debug only to find that when individual short descriptions are edited go back to not showing.

Currently there are some products with a short description, and some without...

The code is just the standard:

```
{$product.short_description nofilter}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on version 4.5.1 upgrade to 4.5.1.SP1.

There was a bug for the categories which caused the same content of the first category to display on every other category page.

> Cache: Layouts: The Same Content Appears In An Html Block For All Categories, Even If The Content Was Configured Individually For Each Category.
>   Posted by caHek on 07 March 2017 - 08:50 AM
>
> Steps to reproduce the issue:
>
> - Go to Design > Layouts, switch to the Categories tab, and create an
>     HTML block.
> - Go to Products < Categories and edit a few categories. Switch to the
>     layouts tab and create unique content in the HTML block for each
>     category.
> - View the category pages on the storefront. The content of the block
>     will be the same for all categories. The content itself depends on
>     which instance of the HTML block was cached first.

Hopefully this solves your problem (otherwise just put it in the bugtracker).